# macOS Sierra - Switch to English input only for several characters

Tags: keyboard, language, input-source

I'm new to Mac, and trying to do the following -

In previous systems, when I was on a non-English input source (e.g. Hebrew), I could mid-sentence hold down the Shift key and type some keys, and they would type as uppercase-English letters. As soon as I would release the Shift key, pressing more keys would return to writing Hebrew.

This is very useful for embedding some English acronyms inside a non-English sentence, like:

אם למישהו יש OCD, הוא לא יאהב את זה שהמשפט כתוב בכיוון לא נכון.

When I try this on a Mac, it either types nothing, or types some weird Hebrew characters with diacritic marks (useless).
Is there any way to do this on Mac?

I have a Sierra MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to System Preferences/Keyboard/Input Sources and activate the Hebrew PC keyboard provided by Apple and use that (instead of Hebrew or Hebrew Qwerty).

Or in system preferences/keyboard/input sources, check the box for using caps lock to change the keyboard to Latin.  That will let you switch to US and back to Hebrew by hitting caps lock, if you find that useful.

Comment: Using the Hebrew PC layout indeed solved it. Thank you!